# PhpStorm ignore file

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

I'm using `webpack` to compile all my JavaScript to a single `bundle.js` file. PhpStorm is running very slowly at times because of this.

Is there a way for me to let PhpStorm ignore this file all together?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"PhpStorm is running very slowly at times because of this"* ? Because of webpack compilation .. or because it needs to re-index that (possibly large) `bundle.js` each time after compilation?

Comment: I think because it needs to reindex it

Comment: You've got the answer already -- I was about to suggest the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the file in the project tool window and select **Mark as plain text** from the context menu. That should keep PHPStorm from inspecting the file.

[image: Mark as plain text]

You can also do the reverse: if a file is marked as plain text, you can right click and mark it back to its regular type.